# How to link accounts with Mobile on Crusaders of the Lost Idols?

Tags: crusaders-of-the-lost-idols

I have a game of CotLI that is pretty far along on PC and would like to continue on mobile. I have found the option to generate a code on PC, but can't seem to find it on mobile.

Does anybody know where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link your Steam version of the Game to the Kongregate version. Then, connect to Kongregate with the game on your phone.